# Why do SVG fragment identifiers without hash not work?

Tags: svg

SVG fragment identifiers are used to link into a particular view of an SVG document. They are defined in [Secion 17.3.2 of the SVG specification 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers).

Usually they have the form `MyDrawing.svg#MyView`, where the part after the hash specifies an id of an element in the linked document. But in my understanding fragment identifiers without a hash like `MyDrawing.svg` should be permitted, too.

Here is what the spec says:

> "If no SVG fragment identifier is provided (e.g, the specified IRI did not contain a "#" character, such as MyDrawing.svg), then the initial view into the SVG document is established using the view specification attributes (i.e., ‘viewBox’, etc.) on the outermost svg element."*

**The test case**

If have set up a small test for this with a HTML file linking to two SVG files. The first file is links using a fragment identifier `img1.svg#id1`, the second one is linked with the identifier `img2.svg`  Here are the files:

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Fragment Identifier Test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>With Hash</h2>
            <div>
                <svg style="width: 128px; height: 128px;">
                    <use xlink:href="img1.svg#id1"></use>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <h2>Without Hash</h2>
            <div>
                <svg style="width: 128px; height: 128px;">
                    <use xlink:href="img2.svg"></use>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

img1.svg (svg element has an id)

```
    <svg id="id1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0,0,512,512">
        <circle cx="256" cy="256" r="200" fill="green" />
    </svg>
```

img2.svg (svg element has no id)

```
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0,0,512,512">
        <circle cx="256" cy="256" r="200" fill="red" />
    </svg>
```

**What is the problem**

All browsers only show the first SVG.

**What is my question?**

My first question is: Do I understand it correctly, that fragment identifiers without hash should be possible according to the SVG spec?

My second question: Am I doing something wrong in my test case or do browsers just not support this?

**Why would we want this?**

In my opinion linking SVG documents using a fragment identifier without hash would be the holy grail to add single SVG images to an HTML document.
The reasons are:

- Simple syntax for including SVG images into HTML documents
- No cluttering of the DOM with unnecessary IDs
- Ability to style SVGs using CSS variables (as demonstrated in [this article on Medium](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/lets-make-your-svg-symbol-icons-multi-colored-with-css-variables-cddd1769fca4)).

In short, we could finally use fully CSS styleable vector graphics that can be stored in a single external file. No injection, no cluttering DOM IDs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fragment identifier is [everything after a hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). MyDrawing.svg is not a fragment identifier at all.

In SVG 1.1 a `<use>` element cannot point to a [complete file](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement) i.e. MyDrawing.svg

> Unlike ‘image’, the ‘use’ element cannot reference entire files.

SVG 2 proposes to remove that limitation but as yet no browser has implemented that part of SVG 2. The SVG 2 specification will have to revert to the SVG 1.1 text unless at least 2 browsers implement the change.

To do this in SVG 1.1 you'd need to use an `<image>` element as the specification itself suggests. Or if you want to use a `<use>` element, put an id on the root element and point the `<use>` element to that.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Using image unfortunately does not seem to work with CSS variables, so the only option would be using an id and a fragment identifier.

Comment: I wish this (`<use>` cannot point to a complete file) were documented in MDN or W3C school.